# how to plot step function on excel?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, graphing-functions

How to plot this step function
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<0\\0.192,&x\in[0,1)\\0.428,&x\in[1,2)\\0.972,&x\in[2,3)\\1,&x\ge3\end{cases}$$

I tried excel using line bar and then changed the axis to date, but the result wasn't good, how should I plot this?

Comment: I recommend always using the scatter plot for graphing any function with an expression like this ... So do you have the points that you want to graph? Or what's the exact difficulty you are facing?

Comment: @MattiP. I know i should plot it as a step up function and I googled and all lead to the saying that you should at first make a line chart and then changing some properties but still it is not look like a proper step up chart. at I just want an image of it being plotted

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** In MS Excel, one way is to arrange the table with blank spaces:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

Note the path: Insert $\to$ Scatter $\to$ Scatter with straight lines and markers. The markers can be customized to make them filled/unfilled/line.

**Method 2:** If you only need the graph (without further calculations), alternatively, you can use desmos.com: see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yug4oyhwu4).

**Method 3:** Yet another option is to use geogebra.org: see [here](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing). Just copy and paste:

if(x<0,0,0≤x<1,0.192,1≤x<2,0.428,2≤x<3,0.972,x≥3,1)

Comment: Nice!..........